# Python Print the variable names in a list

Tags: python, list

How can I print the variable name from a list instead of the value? I can iterate through the list and print the value below but I would like to know how to also iterate through the list and print the variable name?

```
a = 'Red'
b = 'Green'
c = 'Blue'

mylist = [a, b, c]
for i in mylist:
    print(i)
```

Current Output:

```
Red
Green
Blue
```

Desired Output:

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: You would probably want to use a dictionary where your variable name is the `key` and the value is the `value`

Comment: `mylist` contains only *values*.  There is absolutely no remaining connection to the variables that originally provided those values.